# Python set number of arguments to capture

Tags: python

I was working on a project where I doing regressions and I wanted to used `scipy.optomize.curve_fit` which takes a function and tries to find the right parameters for it. The odd part was that it was never given how many parameters the function took. Eventually we guessed that it used `foo.__code__.co_nlocals`, but in the case we would've used it I needed 33  arguments.

To the question: Is there a way use the `def foo(*x)` notation to let python know it needs a certain range of number of arguments? Like a `def foo(*x[:32])`? I'm sure I will never use this in any real code, but it would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way use the def foo(*x) notation to let python know it needs a certain range of number of arguments?

Nope. Also, `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` ultimately gets its argument count information from `f.__code__.co_argcount`, not `co_nlocals` or `n_locals` (which doesn't exist).

Comment: Excellent I fixed the `n_locals ` in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact when you specify the function for the fit it should look like this for instance:

```
def f(x, a, b):
    return a*x**b
```

the first argument is the variable, the other ones are the parameters. Numpy knows that and you do not need to specify the number of parameters explicitly.